# gdalwarp rotates the layer

Tags: gdal

I have a GeoTiff. Initially, it's position is not correct and to make it correct, I use two tools - `gdal_translate` and `gdalwarp`. I took the syntax of the coomads from `QGIS`, so, I guess, it should be right. This is how I do it:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 4838243.731279995 7581258.9526971625 4838243.731279995 7581258.9526971625 -gcp 4839501.660099541 7580353.345120007 4839501.660099541 7580353.345120007 -gcp 4839658.203393867 7580020.911514748 4839658.203393867 7580020.911514748 -gcp 4838016.628872765  7579350.850686316 4838016.628872765 7579350.850686316 -gcp 4837906.764692471 7579085.978855766 4837906.764692471 7579085.978855766 -gcp 4838208.314319817 7578964.682863865 4838208.314319817 7578964.682863865 -gcp 4838227.469082231 7578995.895716031 4838227.469082231  7578995.895716031 -gcp 4838295.043257468 7578978.886410365 4838295.043257468 7578978.886410365 layer_1_.tiff layer_1_tmp.tiff

gdalwarp -r near -order 1 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -dstalpha -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:3857  layer_1_tmp.tiff layer_1_res.tiff
```

So, in fact, what I need is a kind of linear transformation. I do not need any rotations. But for some reason, GDAL rotates the initial GeoTiff by 180 degrees. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Well, it seems like I provided incorrect values for `gdal_translate`. Instead of providing pixel coordinates which have nothing to do with reference systems, I provided geographic coordinates - `gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 4838243.731279995 7581258.9526971625` <-- this is incorrect. But I do not know how can I get pixel coordinate, if I know its geographic coordinate.

Comment: Or, it seems like I found a solution. The idea is to transform a first pair of coordinates to pixel coordinates via gdallocationinfo